# React component not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Embarrassing question, but here we go.

I have a `layout.js` file that is supposed to render out my React components.

#### Layout.j:s

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import MainNavbar from './Navbar'
import AddButton from './AddButton'

export default class Layout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <AddButton />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The `Navbar` component works fine, but my `AddButton` wont display at all. I've tried `console.log`-ging from it and nothing gets outputted in the console. So I guess my problem has to do with my component not getting linked.

Here's the file that won't get displayed:

#### AddButton.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'

export default class AddButton extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('hejsan')
    return (
      <div>
        helloooooo
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is the `index.js` file:

#### index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'

import Layout from './components/Navbar'

const app = document.getElementById('root')

ReactDOM.render(<Layout />, app)
```

I bet my problem is super basic, but I have no idea how to resolve this.
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the mistake is very basic, you have imported `Layout` from `Navbar` which is nothing but your `Navbar` component and hence only `Navbar` is rendered, rather you should have imported it from `Layout.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'

import Layout from './components/Layout'

const app = document.getElementById('root')

ReactDOM.render(<Layout />, app)
```

Also in Layout.js change

```
import MainNavbar from './Navbar'
```

to

```
import Navbar from './Navbar'
```